# How to remove title from any tag?

Tags: html, css

I am using same structure page-1 and page-2 page but remove this title from only page-1 how remove this please help me same code call so i will not change in structure. This is show in hover state so want remove this. Thanks in advance.

```html
<i class="icon-eye icons" title="Quick View"></i>
```

Comment: use `element.removeAttribute('title')` [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var element = document.getElementById(id);
element.removeAttribute("title");
```